# xml parser for IE is not working. loadXML is returing null

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

```
     var xmlDoc;

    try { 
    //For IE 
//This is what i am trying to do.But alas! fails.
    var xmlDoc ;
             xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
             xmlDoc .async = false;
            xmlDoc.loadXML(progressxml);
            var xml = xmlDoc;
    alert(xml);

    } catch(e) {  //if exception than For Firefox etc.
      try { //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.  
      alert("Coming nopt in INE");
        parser=new DOMParser();  
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(progress,"text/xml");  
        } catch(e) {  
        alert(e.message)  
        }  
    } 
    var notes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0];
```

I am trying to parse a xml string in order to display it on various browsers. Code for Firefox is working good.Problem is with IE section.  i.e notes is null. Don't know why??

Sample xml string :

```
<displayvalue>BANGALORE</displayvalue>
<displayvalue>Rishi prakash barawl</displayvalue>
<displayvalue>3.29</displayvalue>
<displayvalue>a¢ ¶ ® Ë Ý &#65533;</displayvalue>
<displayvalue></displayvalue>
<displayvalue>MCA</displayvalue>
```

breaks on special char tagvalue.

Comment: Can you provide a sample xml string?

Comment: Oh Yes! I forgot to mention ,it's working for normal string(without special chars) ..but breaks on a string with. Adding sample xml string in Qus.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure your XML starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` so that the parser that IE uses reads the characters in correctly.

Comment: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ? ....this is what I have written in my Code..it seems good enough to make IE realizes that I am using UTF-8 char set . is there seem any other deficiency?

Comment: I got Some hints that there are some character which are Invalid "According to IE"..need to remove them first ,Any idea how to do that??

Comment: can't say I do - IE knows all unicode characters as long as the XML is correctly indicated as UTF8. Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates this going wrong for IE and link it in your original post?

Comment: Ok I will try to do that..But this is what I think : As I was using ActiveXobject parser for IE and DOMparser for others,I don't know why but on doing loadXML(txt) ,it said "invalid character present in text content",For IE only.I thought may be parser for IE8- is not that rich to understand all XML chars (apparently I am wrong).Wrote a piece of code to remove all non-ascii ,and after that it worked Fine!!! But  "it is Not A Nice Solution ."